# JPA ManyToMany duplicate key issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, orm

I have the following issue. I have 2 entities, Movie and Actor.

[Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmtUC.png)

A movie has multiple actors but an actor can be in multiple movies. Now the problem occurs when I'm trying to add 2 movies that have an actor in common.

Let's say I'm adding deadpool and after that I'm adding deadpool 2. When I'm adding the second movie I get the following error :

> The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint

Now this is valid because jpa is inserting an actor to the database that already exists. I don't know how I can solve this, I get the id's from TheMovieDatabase and I don't want to have duplicate Actors in my database.

**MOVIE:**

```
@Entity(name = "Movie")
public class Movie {

//instance variables
@Positive
@Id
private long tmdbId;

...

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "movie_actor",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_tmdbid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id")
)
private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>();

...
```

**Actor:**

```
@Entity(name = "Actor")
public class Actor {

@Id
private long id;

...

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
```

**Jpa add method**

```
    public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
    try {
        //open connection
        openConnection();

        //check
        if (movie == null) {
            throw new DatabaseException("You cannot add an empty movie");
        }

        //contains only looks in the current persistence context
        if (entityManager.find(Movie.class,movie.getTmdbId()) != null) {
            throw new MovieAlreadyExistsException("This movie already exists!");
        }

        //begin transaction
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        //add movie & commit
        entityManager.persist(movie);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    }catch (MovieAlreadyExistsException error){
        throw new MovieAlreadyExistsException(error.getMessage(),error);
    } catch (Exception error) {
        throw new DatabaseException(error.getMessage(), error);
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

**Method that set's the actors:** It will take the actors from TheMovieDatabase and the addMovie is the one from jpa behind a facade.

```
//add a movie
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public String saveMovie(@ModelAttribute("movie") @Valid Movie movie, BindingResult result) {
    ...

    try{
            //set actors
        Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>(mediaService.getMovieActors(movie.getTmdbId()));
        movie.setActors(actors);

        //add movie with actors
        movieService.addMovie(movie);
```

**StackTrace:**

> Internal Exception: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.DerbySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL180530224955890' defined on 'ACTOR'.
>   Error Code: 20000
>   Call: INSERT INTO ACTOR (ID, MOVIECHARACTER, NAME, PROFILEPICTURE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
>       bind => [4 parameters bound]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(model.movie.actor.Actor@d681)] with root cause
>    ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL180530224955890' defined on 'ACTOR'.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:895)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:967)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:637)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:564)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2093)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:270)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:256)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:405)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:502)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:314)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:810)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2979)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1892)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1874)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1824)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:194)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:139)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4384)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1491)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1581)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:278)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1218)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:134)
>       at model.db.types.MovieDatabaseJpa.addMovie(MovieDatabaseJpa.java:66)
>       at model.MovieService.addMovie(MovieService.java:19)
>       at web.controller.MovieController.saveMovie(MovieController.java:72)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: You should post the complete stack trace of the exception and the code that adds `Actor`s to the `Movie` that is being saved.

Comment: @BheshGurung done

Comment: Seems like it is trying to insert the `Actor`s which were just retrieved. Try this - instead of getting and setting `Actor`s in `saveMovie`, do that in `addMovie`, so that retrieving `Actor`s and saving `Movie` happens in the same Hibernate session/transaction.

Comment: Also, the way you are (manually) handling the connection/session/transaction, like in your `addMovie` method, is a very poor practice, especially, when you are using a framework like Spring.

Comment: @BheshGurung that service is retrieving actors from TheMovieDatabase api and is not done in a jpa transaction. When the jpa transaction is taking place, the actors are already set in the movie object

Connection, yes I know but it's for a school prototype.

Comment: In that case, once you get the actors from the api, you need to reconcile that list with your local database first. i.e. make sure to insert a record for each new `Actor` from the api, skipping the ones that are already there. Then you can move on to insert the `Movie`.

Comment: Okay I will try that tomorrow

Comment: @BheshGurung I have solved the issue by using merge instead of persist because if the actor already exists if will update it.

Comment: Sounds great! Not sure why merge didn't occur to me. But you should write an aswer to this one solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue:

I have used merge instead of persist because if the entity exists it will update it otherwise insert it.